# Forseeing issues when upgrading from Spring 3.0.5 to Spring 3.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-security, upgrade

On my current project we are using Spring 3.0.5 (core, aop, beans, web , webmvc, etc). However we want to use "Spring Security SAML Extension 1.0.0 RC3" to build a Service Provider, which has been thoroughly tested with Spring 3.1.2, Spring Security 3.1.2 and OpenSAML 2.5.3.

What are the major problems we could encounter when upgrading from Spring 3.0.5 to Spring 3.1.2? How backward compatible would Spring Security 3.1.2 be with Spring 3.0.5?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The update from Spring 3.0 to Spring 3.1 is relative easy. Only if you have custom `WebArgumentResolver`, then you should replace them with `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

The Update from Spring Security 3.0 to Spring Securiy 3.1 was even more easy.

But for more details have a look at Spring Reference:

- [Chapter "New Features and Enhancements in Spring Framework 3.1"](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.1)
- **[Appendix C. Migrating to Spring Framework 3.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#migration-3.1)** -- So your question is even answered in the Reference Documentation!!

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware about the Appendix.